# Как сделать так, чтоб нельзя было в конструктор передать NULL?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так, чтоб нельзя было в конструктор передать NULL?

Comment: В конструктор чего? Собственного класса или чего-то другого? В данной формулировке вопрос слишком общий чтобы конкретно ответить на него.

Comment: Вы изобретаете костыль. Точнее, у вас есть какая-то проблема, и вы хотите решить ее, запретив передавать null, что есть костыль. Опишите лучше конкретную проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По спецификации java, передать null в конструктор  можно (да и не суть, что в конструктор, присвоить null можно любому объекту) и обратиться потом к нему и получить NPE.

Как же быть?

1) Optional (java 8, либо Guava)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Не спасает от NPE. Java - это обязательная проверка на NPE, на этапе компиляции javac не может определить, что возникнет NPE, поэтому Optional это более удобный синтаксис для проверки на null.

2) Не писать на java, а попробовать Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

На нем ты либо не присвоишь null, либо обязательно инициализируешь объект, либо пропишешь поведение на null, иначе не скомпилируется.

Comment: Позволю себе поправить. Optional - это своеобразный способ сказать, что заключенное в нем значение имеет право быть null, e.g. это может быть результат запроса в кэш, и непосредственно к отделению зерен отношения не имеет. Конкретно в Java проще всего либо сделать первой строкой `Objects.requireNonNull()` (выкинет NPE, но до того, как кто-то начнет работать со значением), либо вручную проверить и выкинуть IllegalArgumentException.